# Merging multiple associated rows

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `Trackings(visitor_id, field, value, type)` which records dynamic/user-defined fields

I want to merge `visitor A` and `visitor B`, such that for every tracking in `A`, override it in `B`. In other words, override all the trackings in `B` with the corresponding in `A` (they don't need to have all the same fields specified at the merge)

Example:

```
visitor_id  field           value       type
A           name            Jack        string
A           orders          5           integer
B           orders          2           integer
B           age             30          integer
B           signed_up_at    1/1/1990    date
```

Merging Visitor A with B should yield

```
visitor_id  field           value           type
B           orders          5               integer
B           age             30              integer
B           signed_up_at    1/1/1990        date    
B           name            Jack
```

Ideally this should be quite performant

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query to see the partial results

```
SELECT B.*, A.*
FROM yourTable B
FULL JOIN yourTable A
  ON B.field = A.field
 AND B.visitor_id = 'B' 
 AND A.visitor_id = 'A'
```

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/RXHYW61916)**

```
SELECT 'B' as visitor_id,
       COALESCE(A.field, B.field) as field,
       COALESCE(A.value, B.value) as value,
       COALESCE(A.type, B.type) as type
FROM yourTable B
FULL JOIN yourTable A
  ON B.field = A.field
 AND B.visitor_id = 'B' 
 AND A.visitor_id = 'A'
WHERE B.visitor_id = 'B' 
   OR A.visitor_id = 'A'
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Would this be performant? Also, I am looking for an UPDATE query